# Dialogflow - Parameter is not updated with user responses

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

Recently i found a problem with Dialogflow parameters. I have a intent with 2 required parameter `sector` & `stockVolume`. Where `sector` is a define entity and `stockVolume` is a `@sys.number`.

I realize if I enter a query with only the `stockVolume` "A", it prompts for the `sector` (which is the right thing to do)

BUT if the next input includes a sector and a NEW `stockVolume` "B", dialogflow is unable to store "B".The parameters will record "A" and the `sector` provided in the second input.

[image: see pic for details]

```
{  "responseId": "517fa3bc-d54b-4da6-a7fe-9bf1cbf10fe9", 
"queryResult": {
"queryText": "set stock volume for n09 to be 1287",
"parameters": {
  "sector": "N09",
  "stockVolume": "230000"
},
"allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
"fulfillmentText": "Sure! I will update N09's stock value to 230000*",
"fulfillmentMessages": [
  {
    "text": {
      "text": [
        "Sure! I will update N09's stock value to 230000*"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the report, we're looking into this!

Comment: Update: I've confirmed that this issue no longer occurs.

Comment: Are you sure?? I'm still facing this issue as of now... Can you tell me what is the solution?